# Primefaces datatable with selection attribute - dynamic tables

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dynamic, datatable, accordion

First some explain:

I create dynamically an accordeonpanel and in each Tab i create a p:datatable ( also dynamically).

I now have to edit the lines of the tables but my method in the "selection" is not called. 
I think it's because of the above explained dynamism.

the method is: evaluationController.deleteIndicator()

Does anyone have an idea how to fix that?

Here the code:

XHTML:

```
<!-- **************************************** ACCORDEON **************************************** -->
            <p:panel id="mainAccordeonHeader" header="Capacités et dégrés de maîtrise" styleClass="panelSearch">
                <h:form id="evalAccordionForm" styleClass="orgForm">      

                    <p:accordionPanel id="evalAccordion" 
                                      styleClass="orgAccordion" 
                                      value="#{evaluationController.availableCapacitys}"
                                      var="capListItem">
                        <p:tab id="evalAccordTitle">
                            <f:facet name="title">
                                <h:panelGrid columns="4">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{capListItem.name}"/>                                      
                                    <h:outputText value="#{capListItem.isThresholdOfSuccess ? 'Capacité Déterminante' : 'Degré de Maitrise'}" />
                                    <h:outputText value="Nr Indicateurs: #{evaluationController.findNumberOfIndicators(capListItem)}"/>
                                    <h:outputText value="Pondération: #{evaluationController.findCapacityPonderation(capListItem)}"/>
                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </f:facet>
                            <!-- CAPACITY DETAIL-->
                            <table border="0" >
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>
                                            <p>Description</p>
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            <p style="float: right">Pondération</p>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>                                     
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <p:inputTextarea id="capDescTextArea" rows="3" cols="113" value="#{capListItem.description}" readonly="true"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p:inputTextarea style="float: right" id="capPonderationTextArea"  rows="1" cols="1" readonly="true" value="#{evaluationController.findCapacityPonderation(capListItem)}"/>                                           
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>                                    
                            <p:separator />
                            <!-- INDICATORS-->
                            <h:form>
                                <p:contextMenu for="indicatorTable">                               
                                    <p:menuitem value="Modifier" update="indicatorTable" icon="ui-icon-wrench" actionListener="#{evaluationcontroller.updateIndicator()}"/>
                                    <p:menuitem value="Supprimer" update="indicatorTable" icon="ui-icon-trash" actionListener="#{evaluationController.deleteIndicator()}"/>
                                    <p:menuitem value="Ajouter" update="indicatorTable" icon="ui-icon-plus" actionListener="#{evaluationController.addIndicator()}"/>
                                    <p:separator/>
                                     <p:menuitem value="Annuler action"/>
                                </p:contextMenu>
                                <p:dataTable
                                    id="indicatorTable"
                                    value="#{evaluationController.findIndicatorsByCapacity(capListItem)}"                                      
                                    var="indicator"
                                    editable="true"
                                    tableStyle="indicatorTableStyle"     
                                    rowKey="#{indicator.id}"
                                    selection="#{evaluationcontroller.selectedIndicatorRow}" selectionMode="single"
                                    >
                                    <f:facet name="header">Les Indicateurs ( #{evaluationController.findNumberOfIndicators(capListItem)})
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <p:column headerText="Org Ut" >
                                        <h:outputText value ="#{indicator.organizedUt.id}"/>
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Date">
                                        <h:outputText value ="#{indicator.organizedUt.toString()}"/>
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Nom">
                                        <h:outputText value ="#{indicator.name}"/>
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Description" toggleable="false" width="450">
                                        <p:outputLabel value ="#{indicator.description}"  />
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Max" toggleable="false" width="30">
                                        <p:inputTextarea style="float: none"   rows="1" cols="1" readonly="true" value="#{indicator.maxPossible}"/> 
                                    </p:column>
                                </p:dataTable>    
                                <p:commandButton styleClass="addButtonStyle" icon="ui-icon-plus" value="Ajouter un indicateur"/> 
                                <p:commandButton styleClass="deleteAllButtonStyle" icon="ui-icon-trash" value="Supprimer tous les indicateurs" actionListener="#{evaluationController.deleteIndicator()}"/> 

                            </h:form>
                        </p:tab>
                    </p:accordionPanel>   
                </h:form>
            </p:panel>
```

CONTROLER:

Here is the problem : the Getter Setter are not called when i select a row!

```
public Indicator getSelectedIndicatorRow() {
    System.out.println("GETTER - selectedIndicatorRow");
    return selectedIndicatorRow;
}

public void setSelectedIndicatorRow(Indicator selectedIndicatorRow) {
    this.selectedIndicatorRow = selectedIndicatorRow;
    System.out.println("SETTER - selectedIndicatorRow");
}


public void deleteIndicator(){
    System.out.println("Function: deleteIndicator");
    try {
        System.out.println("TRY TO DELETE  INDICATOR");
        indicatorFacade.remove(selectedIndicatorRow);

        List<Indicator> tempIndicatorsList = actualGridHM.get(selectedIndicatorRow.getCapacity());
        actualGridHM.remove(selectedIndicatorRow.getCapacity());
        tempIndicatorsList.remove(selectedIndicatorRow);
        actualGridHM.put(selectedIndicatorRow.getCapacity(), tempIndicatorsList);
        System.out.println("INDICATOR DELETED!");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR - DELETE OF INDICATOR NOT WORKED!");
    }
```

Does anyone have a solution?   Maybe an another way to edit this dynamic table ( placed in a dynamic accordeon)??

Answer (score 0):

First obvious problem with your code is that you have two `<h:form>`. You have to delete the inner `<h:form>` and test again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way below;
put your command buttons in facets at the bottom of your datatable like

```html
<p:dataTable>
  ...
  <f:facet>
    <p:commandButton styleClass="addButtonStyle" icon="ui-icon-plus" value="Ajouter un indicateur"/> 
    <p:commandButton styleClass="deleteAllButtonStyle" icon="ui-icon-trash" value="Supprimer tous les indicateurs" action="#{evaluationController.deleteIndicator}"/> 
  </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>
```

and use "action" attribute instead of "actionListener" without '()' at the end of your action method in your command button or   add ActionEvent parameter to your action method.